# Delete Row and Rename Worksheets From cell value, part 2

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rename, popupwindow

Using the code from user3598756 works fine, [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552248/delete-row-and-rename-worksheets-from-cell-value), except up to 1 point.

If I want to delete the first team, nr 1, it gives me a popup to select a file. It wants to update/use a Sheet called BT0, which doesn't exist and never will exist. See screenshot.

BT1 is the first sheet of the list of sheets.

My question is how I can avoid this?

Screenshot

[image: 1]

```
Sub Team_Verwijderen()
Dim Zoekwaarde As Variant Zoekwaarde = InputBox("Vul het BT-nummer in dat je wilt verwijderen.")

On Error GoTo Errohandler

    Dim intMyVal As Long
        intMyVal = CLng(Zoekwaarde) 'Value to search for, change as required.
        
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastRowVBG As Long
        lngLastRow = Blad1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column A, change as required.
        lngLastRowVBG = Blad4.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column M, change as required.

        Dim foundCel As Range, foundCelVBG As Range ' look range A3:A... for the input value
        Set foundCel = Blad1.Range("A3:A" & lngLastRow).Find(what:=intMyVal, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundCelVBG = Blad4.Range("M3:M" & lngLastRow).Find(what:="BT" & intMyVal, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
            If foundCel Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "BT-Team niet gevonden!"
            Else
                'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    Sheets("BT" & intMyVal).Delete ' delete the worksheet
                'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                
                Dim iRow As Long 'loop through sheets following the deleted one
                    For iRow = foundCel.Row + 1 To lngLastRow
                        Blad1.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(intMyVal) 'rewrite the sequence and the name reference of the current loop sheet
                        Blad1.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(, 1).Select
                                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'BT" & intMyVal & "'!A1"
                        Sheets("BT" & intMyVal + 1).Name = "BT" & intMyVal ' rename the current loop sheet
                        Sheets("BT" & intMyVal).Range("A11").Formula = "=IF(OR(RC[2]=""JA"",RC[2]=""J""),'BT" & intMyVal - 1 & "'!R[279]C+1,'BT" & intMyVal - 1 & "'!R[279]C+0)"
                                                         
                        intMyVal = intMyVal + 1
                    Next
                    
                        If Range("A" & lngLastRow).Value <> 1 Then
                            Intersect(Blad1.Range("A:K"), foundCel.EntireRow).Delete xlUp '
                            Intersect(Blad4.Range("M:R"), foundCelVBG.EntireRow).Delete xlUp '
                        Else
                            Blad1.Range("B3:K3").ClearContents
                            Blad4.Range("M3:R3").Delete xlUp
                            Blad4.Range("F7:J9, F11:J18").ClearContents
                        End If
            End If
            
Blad11.Select

    Dim foundCelGemarkeerd As Range
        Set foundCelGemarkeerd = Blad11.Range("C4:C253").Find(what:=0, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
'MsgBox foundCelGemarkeerd

If foundCelGemarkeerd Is Nothing Then
    Blad1.Range("B3").Select

Else
    Intersect(Range("A:C"), foundCelGemarkeerd.EntireRow).Delete xlUp

End If
Blad1.Select Range("B3").Select

MsgBox "BT" & Zoekwaarde & " verwijderd!", vbOKOnly, "BT-team verwijderd"

Errohandler: Range("B3").Select

End Sub
```

Who can help me?

The problem is that I don't understand the loop part enough to see where it goes wrong and how to fix it.

If I delete team 1, it needs to start at sheet BT2 and rename to BT1. Now it looks like it wants to start at sheet BT0, which does not exist and never will.

Comment: I neither understand your code nor what it is intended to do nor do I want to read referred older questions first. Just a wild guess: It should probably be `Sheets("BT" & intMyVal + 1).Range("A11")`. You should learn to use the debugger to understand what is going on in your code. And you shouldn't simply copy code written by someone else without understanding what it does.